# setState not work by onChange inside useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using useState Hook to store a form to manage view when user click. The interface display good but I cannot enter value in the input field. Can anyone tell me why? thanks.

```
const [url, seturl] = useState({url: ''});
const changeUrl = (field) => (event) => {
    seturl({
    ...url,
    [field]: event.target.value,
   });
 };
const [step, setStep] = useState(
   <form>
     <input type="text" value={url.url} onChange={changeUrl('url')}/>
    </form>
);
return (
  <div>{step}</div>
);
```

Comment: Why you are taking form as a state ? you are not setting state (setStep) while updating input. You can achieve this in a quite simple way. Kindly check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing something to the function on `onChange` you need to call it like:

```
onChange={e => seturl({ url: e.target.value })}
```

Or you can simply achieve this by doing:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

return (
  <div>
    <form>
     <input type="text" value={url} onChange={e => setUrl(e.target.value)}/>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

The take away from the above example is use hooks to facilitate yourself and get rid of managing the object. If you have more fields like `url` and `page`, you can create multiple states like:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
const [page, setPage] = useState('');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Tong Answer Updated. This will work for you now with object too.

Comment: it not working @Zeeshan, I cannot type anything. Am I missing something?                                              
                                                                                                                            
     
    
    `const [url, setUrl] = useState({url: ''"});

    const [step, setStep] = useState(
       <form>
         <input type="text" value={url.url} onChange={e => setUrl({ url: e.target.value 
     })}/>
       </form>
    );

    return (
    <div>{step}</div>
    )
    }`

Comment: I created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-grothendieck-p93no  The issue is you are rendering the input box via `state`. The state doesn't get updated and that's why it is not re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks for full suppor @Zeeshan, I undertood your solution. So I cannot use useState to store a form like my implementation?

Comment: Yes. You can return `JSX`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `changeURL` function onChange, not everytime.

With your code, changeUrl('url') is fired on each render.
To avoid this, you need to call it as a function, with the event of your input field : `onChange={e => changeUrl(e)}`

Comment: Thanks for your solution, @TBouder. So with my implementation, changeUrl('url') function will be fired on each render and with any times I enter, it will not run the function. But why can I use it outside the useState?

Answer (score 1):

```
 const [url, seturl] = useState("url");

  const changeUrl = event => {
    seturl( event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={url} onChange={(e)=>changeUrl(e)} />
        <p>URL: {url}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I want to store element in useState to use for change view between form input. But with my implementation, I cannot type anything in the input field.

Comment: Did you try my solution? what else do you need to update ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It worked, I know. But I want to use useState to store JSX because I want to change the view of form (ex: use a button to change view from form SignIn and SignUp) but when I store like my implementation, i cannot catch type anything in the input field.

Comment: You don't need to store a whole JSX in State. You can add a logic and control jsx view. for example: for signin and signup button you can use something like: [isAccount, setIsAccount] = useState(false);
and in jsx: {isAccount ? loginBtn : signUpBtn} add logic for isAccount state as per your need

Comment: I got it, Thanks @waqas